# Dropbox OAuth token

Tags: objective-c, xcode, dropbox

Does anyone know how to use Auth tokens for dropbox in objective c iPad/iphone developing on Xcode?? I have searched many tutorials and the closest I have found is this:

http://code.google.com/p/oauthconsumer/wiki/UsingOAuthConsumer

but it is for mac. What I want to do is to link all the app users to the same dropbox account (mine) without displaying the safari window for signing in.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible, but *not* recommended.

**WARNING**: This would allow anyone access to read/write to your dropbox account (or App folder, depending on what access you allow).

I presume you are setting your App up as recommended in the Getting Started Guide:
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/authentication#ios

Here's how it works: once you login to Dropbox, you are re-directed back to your app.  Dropbox does this by getting you to register a URL Scheme and making use of the following AppDelegate method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url;
```

Dropbox passes the `oauth_token`, `oauth_token_secret`, and `uid` in the `url` parameter.  It then saves these for later use when you make API calls by using the following method of `DBSession`:

```
- (BOOL)handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url;
```

So what you can do it create an app that uses the same `App Key` and `Secret`.

**TEST APP**

```
DBSession* dbSession =
    [[[DBSession alloc]
      initWithAppKey:@"APP_KEY"
      appSecret:@"APP_SECRET"
      root:ACCESS_TYPE] // either kDBRootAppFolder or kDBRootDropbox
     autorelease];
[DBSession setSharedSession:dbSession];
```

Request authorization

```
if (![[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
    [[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:yourRootController];
}
```

And then add the AppDelegate method to receive the authorization `url`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    if ([[DBSession sharedSession] handleOpenURL:url]) {
        if ([[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
            NSLog(@"App linked successfully! url: %@", url);
            // At this point you can start making API calls
        }
        return YES;
    }
    // Add whatever other url handling code your app requires here
    return NO;
}
```

This will log the `url` with the authorization token.  Copy that, then in your production app (right after you configure your DBSession) just do this (replacing the string with the one you previously copied):

**PRODUCTION APP**

```
DBSession* dbSession =
    [[[DBSession alloc]
      initWithAppKey:@"APP_KEY"
      appSecret:@"APP_SECRET"
      root:ACCESS_TYPE] // either kDBRootAppFolder or kDBRootDropbox
     autorelease];
[DBSession setSharedSession:dbSession];

if (![[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
    [[DBSession sharedSession] handleOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"db-APP_KEY://1/connect?oauth_token=********&oauth_token_secret=********&uid=********"]];
}
```

This will automatically link the `DBSession` to your Dropbox account.

You can test this by calling this just before you authorize:

```
[[DBSession sharedSession] unlinkAll];
```

**ANOTHER WARNING**
I could just download your app, extract the authorization token, and then start making all the read/write API calls I want.  This is completely insecure and should only be regarded as an educational exercise.

Comment: i followed your steps but it give me `[ERROR] unable to verify link request` error. sdk privacy is changed?. i want to do same functionality. Help would be appriciated.